# Scintilla: single line mode

Tags: c++, scintilla

It is possible to set the single line mode for Scintilla?
In the [documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html), I found a mention about it, but can't find how to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no, and there are no plans to add it. This have been commented by the owner of the project to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/1152/) feature request.